# Updating int column of all rows that satisfy datediff constraint?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, timestamp, azure-functions

I have a function running every 30 seconds and I want to update a column in all the rows where the `current time - table.lastStoredTime > 5 minutes`.

The `lastStoredTime` is a datetime column and I can't seem to get anything to work well.

## Attempt (Doesn't update rows)

```
SELECT  
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.lastStoredTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Mtime 
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE 
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t.lastStoredTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

test setup:

```
create table Transaction_tbl (id int identity(1,1) not null, lastStoredTime datetime2(7), intcol int)
insert into Transaction_tbl 
          select dateadd(minute,-7,sysdatetime()), 0
union all select dateadd(minute,-6,sysdatetime()), 0
union all select dateadd(minute,-5,sysdatetime()), 0
union all select dateadd(minute,-4,sysdatetime()), 0
union all select dateadd(minute,-3,sysdatetime()), 0
```

queries:

```
/* select */
select *,
  datediff(minute, t.lastStoredTime, sysdatetime()) as Mtime 
from Transaction_tbl t 
where t.lastStoredTime < dateadd(minute,-5,sysdatetime())

/* as an update */
update t
  set intcol = intcol+1
output inserted.*
from Transaction_tbl t 
where t.lastStoredTime < dateadd(minute,-5,sysdatetime())
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TXYXT83237

select output:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+-------+
| id |   lastStoredTime    | intcol | Mtime |
+----+---------------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 2017-08-22 19:31:52 |      0 |     7 |
|  2 | 2017-08-22 19:32:52 |      0 |     6 |
|  3 | 2017-08-22 19:33:52 |      0 |     5 |
+----+---------------------+--------+-------+
```

update output:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+
| id |   lastStoredTime    | intcol |
+----+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2017-08-22 19:31:52 |      1 |
|  2 | 2017-08-22 19:32:52 |      1 |
|  3 | 2017-08-22 19:33:52 |      1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+
```

---

Update using a `case` expression:

```
update t
  set intcol = case when t.lastStoredTime < dateadd(minute,-5,sysdatetime()) 
      then intcol+1
      else intcol-1
      end
output inserted.*
from Transaction_tbl t
```

output:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+
| id |   lastStoredTime    | intcol |
+----+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2017-08-22 19:47:14 |      2 |
|  2 | 2017-08-22 19:48:14 |      2 |
|  3 | 2017-08-22 19:49:14 |     -1 |
|  4 | 2017-08-22 19:50:14 |     -1 |
|  5 | 2017-08-22 19:51:14 |     -1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Is it possible to have the column update to a different value if the inequality isn't satisfied?

Comment: @RyanShocker In that case you can use a `case` expression.

Answer (score 0):

use following sql statement

`SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.lastStoredTime, GetDate())
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t.lastStoredTime, GetDate()) > 5`

Comment: Would you know why t.lastStoredTime comes up as invalid column name for me? The column type is datetime and it clearly exists in my table.

Comment: I have executed this statment on a table of one of my databases and it runs fine. Can you please give the error text you are getting by executing the command?

Comment: Intellisense update error was the problem. Required a reboot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a column, why are you using a select statement?
You should be using an update statement:

```
UPDATE Transaction_tbl 
SET <YourColumnName> = <Value>
WHERE t.lastStoredTime <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
```

Of cource, `<YourColumnName>` and `<Value>` are placeholders.

Please note I didn't use `DATEDIFF`, but instead compared the value of the column with the 5 minutes before the current date and time (using `DATEADD` and `GETDATE`).
The reason for this is that using the `DATEDIFF` version prevents SQL Server from using any indexes that might be relevant for the sql statement (and not just `DATEDIFF`, any function will do it).
By comparing the actual value of the column to a computed value, SQL Server can use any indexes that might help performance.

Comment: Perfect, can I have the SET run an else condition as well?

Comment: So if the constraint isn't satisfied, the <YourColumnName> value is set to something other than <Value>

Comment: SqlZim's answer already covers this question. see the part with the case expression.